# How to extract values from jquery `formData` to insert into Mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

My code is about submitting a `multipart form`, through `$.ajax`, which is successfully doing it & upon `json_encode` in `submit.php` , its giving me this :

```
{"success":"Image was submitted","formData":{"fb_link":"https:\/\/www.google.mv\/",
"show_fb":"1",
"filenames":[".\/uploads\/homepage-header-social-icons\/27.jpg"]}}
```

Can someone explain me, in `submit.php`, how can i extract values from `formData`, to store in mysql table ? I have tried, so many things including :

```
 $fb_link = formData['fb_link'];
 $show_fb = formData['show_fb'];
```

and

```
$arr = json_encode($data);
$fb_link=$arr['fb_link'];
```

and

```
$fb_link = REQUEST['fb_link'];
 $show_fb = REQUEST['show_fb'];
```

but, nothing seems to work ? Any Guesses ?

Thanks

update :
JS code on parent-page is :

```
      $(function()
      {
      // Variable to store your files
      var files;

      // Add events
      $('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);
      $('form#upload_form').on('submit', uploadFiles);

      // Grab the files and set them to our variable
      function prepareUpload(event)
      {
      files = event.target.files;
      }

      // Catch the form submit and upload the files
      function uploadFiles(event)
      {
      event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
      event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening

      // START A LOADING SPINNER HERE

      // Create a formdata object and add the files
      var data = new FormData();
      $.each(files, function(key, value)
      {
      data.append(key, value);
      });

      //var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);


      $.ajax({
      url: 'jquery_upload_form_submit.php?files=files',
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,

      //data: {data, var1:"fb_link" , var2:"show_fb"},

      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false, // Don't process the files
      contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
      {
      if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
      {
      // Success so call function to process the form
      submitForm(event, data);
      }
      else
      {
      // Handle errors here
      console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
      }
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
      {
      // Handle errors here
      console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
      // STOP LOADING SPINNER
      }
      });
      }

      function submitForm(event, data)
      {
      // Create a jQuery object from the form
      $form = $(event.target);

      // Serialize the form data
      var formData = $form.serialize();

      // You should sterilise the file names
      $.each(data.files, function(key, value)
      {
      formData = formData + '&filenames[]=' + value;
      });

      $.ajax({
      url: 'jquery_upload_form_submit.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
      {
      if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
      {
      // Success so call function to process the form
      console.log('SUCCESS: ' + data.success);
      }
      else
      {
      // Handle errors here
      console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
      }
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
      {
      // Handle errors here
      console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
      },
      complete: function()
      {
      // STOP LOADING SPINNER
      }
      });
      }
      });
```

*UPDATE CODE OF - submit.php* :

```
    <?php

    // Here we add server side validation and better error handling :)
    $data = array();
    if(isset($_GET['files'])) {
    $error = false;
    $files = array();

    $uploaddir = './uploads/homepage-header-social-icons/';

    foreach ($_FILES as $file) {

    if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . basename($file['name']))) {
    $files[] = $uploaddir . $file['name'];
    //$files = $uploaddir . $file['name'];
    }


    else {
    $error = true;
    }
    }

    $data = ($error) ? array('error' => 'There was an error uploading your image-files') : array('files' => $files);
    }


    else {

    $data = array(
    'success' => 'Image was submitted',
    'formData' => $_POST
    );
    }

    echo json_encode($data); 



    ?>
```

Comment: You need to provide some more information; like the code snippet of the part of your JavaScript that is doing the `ajax`, especially what exactly you are sending. Depending on that, you should do either `print_r( $_POST )`  or  `print_r( $_POST )`  in the `submit.php` script and show the output

Comment: @OlowookereEmmanuel May i know, why its needed, when i pasted entire output of `json_decode` ? I hope this code n question , is self-sufficient to explain the issues ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using POST method in ajax, then you can access those data in PHP.

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Form submit using ajax.

```
//Program a custom submit function for the form
$("form#data").submit(function(event){
  //disable the default form submission
  event.preventDefault();
  //grab all form data  
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
  $.ajax({
      url: 'formprocessing.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (returndata) {
         alert(returndata);
      }
  });
  return false;
});
```

You can access the data on PHP

```
$json = '{"countryId":"84","productId":"1","status":"0","opId":"134"}';
$json = json_decode($json, true);
echo $json['countryId'];
echo $json['productId'];
echo $json['status'];
echo $json['opId'];
```

If you want to access file object, you need to use `$_FILES`

```
$profileImg = $_FILES['profileImg'];
$displayImg = $_FILES['displayImg'];
```

Comment: Thanks ! But, dear, I am trying to access $_POST data, which i cannt. I have updated the Code, to see more details.

Comment: Can you see the ajax sending data to server in console ? or it's showing any errors ?

Comment: Console gives : {"success":"Image was submitted","formData":{"fb_link":"https:\/\/www.google.mv\/",
"show_fb":"1",
"filenames":[".\/uploads\/homepage-header-social-icons\/27.jpg"]}}

Comment: As u can see, formData contains all needed data, now i want to extract this data individually to INSERT INTO mysql table

Comment: How to get fb_link & show_fb values ? print_r($_POST); gives me empty Array()

Comment: Can you change URL to "url: 'jquery_upload_form_submit.php'" instead of url: 'jquery_upload_form_submit.php?files=files'

Comment: And check the URL and other params of ajax are properly calling while ajax request and that ajax request gives 200 status in the network part of the console..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124146/discussion-between-luna-romania-and-loading).

Comment: Please be mindful that multiple <select> options are serialized under the same key, like - result in a query string that includes multiple occurences of the same query parameter.N this form contains, <select>.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is different in terms that :
1. Its sending MULTIPLE files, to upload
2. Contains a SELECT
3. Contains an INPUT

So, images are serialized & sent via GET . And, rest FORM data is being sent via POST. So Solution is :

```
 var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
```

inside :  function      uploadFiles(event){}

And in submit.php :

```
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_GET);
die();
```

This will give you both values. Then comment these & as per the Code, make these changes :

```
$filename_wpath =  serialize($files);
$fb_link = $_POST['fb_link'];
$show_fb = $_POST['show_fb'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO `tblbasicheader`(fldFB_image, fldFB_link, fldHideShow)
            VALUES('$filename_wpath','$fb_link','$show_fb')";

mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

Works like Charm ! :)